# Do threads sleep when waiting on a locked mutex?

Tags: c++, multithreading, mutex, sleep

Do threads blocked by a `std::mutex::lock()` or a condition variable sleep in a way that frees the core for other processes, or am I required to manually put these threads to sleep?  And if true, would `std::mutex::try_lock()` allow for a way to spin the thread without sleeping?

The reason I ask: I want to have three states for threads in my thread pool that are unused: spinning for 2 milliseconds, then locked by a mutex for 250-ish milliseconds (assuming this lets them sleep and unhog the core), then finally being deallocated.

I want to avoid calling sleep manually if I can help it, tuning the sleep duration would be hard.  So can I safely leave that to the mutex?

Comment: Yes, a thread sleeping on a mutex uses essentially no CPU time.

Comment: "So can I safely leave that to the mutex?" you should. Libraries usually written by experienced programmers, outsmart their implementation is not a trivial task. So you better use default implementation and look for more complicated solution only if necessary.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

That is implementation specific; the C++ standard does not speak to it directly.

In practice, mutexes may use a combination of spin lock and full sleep.  Sleeping and waking up is relatively expensive, and a compiler may write the locks to spin for a few ms before putting the thread to sleep.

No C++ implementation on a major phone, PC or big iron is going to spin lock indefinitely however.  I could imagine some embedded system doing so, but have not personally encountered one.

Answer (score 5):

Yes. Such blocked threads sleep and don't take up any CPU cycles.